# realm react native IN not working

Tags: react-native, realm

I tried to use `IN` in realm react native.

```
realm.objects('User').filtered('id IN {1,2,3}');
```

but this error appeared: `id IN {1,2,3}:1:0: Invalid predicate.`

what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the `IN` predicate is not yet supported in Realm JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

as Kristian said IN is not supported in Realm but you can do something like this if your id is int:

```
realm.objects('User').filtered('id < 4 AND id > 0');
```